# Remove all non-alpha characters from string

Tags: c++

Is there a way how to remove all non-alpha characters (i.e. `,.?!` etc) from `std::string` while not deleting czech symbols like `ščéř`? I tried using:

```
std::string FileHandler::removePunctuation(std::string word) {
    for (std::string::iterator i = word.begin(); i != word.end(); i++) {
        if (!isalpha(word.at(i - word.begin()))) {
            word.erase(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return word;    
}
```

but it deletes czech characters.

In the best case, I'd like to use `toLowerCase` for those symbols too.

Comment: Try adjusting the [`locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha)

Comment: If you want to remove punctuation as the function name says, there's a `std::ispunct` function.

Comment: Which is the encoding you are using for the `std::string`? C++ is not utf8 aware per se so working with a `std::string` that contains utf8 data won't work as expected since each element of the string doesn't correspond to a real character. `isalpha` can work with `std::wstring` or `std::u16string` if properly providing a locale.

Comment: It helps a lot, but it still does not remove quotation notes.

Comment: @JakubGruber Are all the characters you want removed punctuation characters?  If not, what other characters that would *not* be considered punctuation characters do you want removed?

Comment: Basically, I want to remove everything but alphanumeric character.

Comment: @JakubGruber - I posted an answer, but you may still have issues with the locale.  So YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::remove_if` along with `erase`:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
//...
std::wstring FileHandler::removePunctuation(std::wstring word) 
{
    word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), 
                  [](char ch){ return !::iswalnum(ch); }), word.end());
    return word;
}
```

Comment: I tried that by small modification (changing `!::iswalnum(ch)` to `::ispunct(ch)`. It works fine for czech words, but I am having problem with `“`

Comment: Looks like the left double quotation mark (not the ASCII double quote) is not considered a punctuation character, at least in the locale you're using.   You can replace or adjust the lambda to do your own check, but the answer is how you should write the erasure code, in general, instead of looping.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwctype>
// if windows, add this: #include <io.h>
// if windows, add this: #include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  // if windows, add this: _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_U16TEXT );
  std::wstring s( L"š1č2é3ř!?" );
  for ( auto c : s )
    if ( std::iswalpha( c ) )
      std::wcout << c;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")` you can use `std::iswalpha()` to figure out, if something is a letter.

So the following program

```
#include <cwctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    std::wstring youreWelcome = L"Není zač.";

    for ( auto c : youreWelcome )
        if ( std::iswalpha(c) )
            std::wcout << c;

    std::wcout << std::endl;
}
```

will print

```
Nenízač
```

to the console.

Note that `std::setlocale()` might not be thread-safe by itself nor in conjunction with certain other functions that are executed concurrently such as `std::iswalpha()`. Therefore, it should only be used in single-threaded code like program start-up code. More concretely, you should not call `std::setlocale()` from within `FileHandler::removePunctuation()` but only `std::iswalpha()` if you need it.

Answer (score -1):

You might have to write a custom version of isalpha. From what you describe it seems like it only returns true for a-z and A-Z.

Comment: `isalpha` uses the current locale.  Be default that means just regular english characters.